SVG is not showing correctly, when used as mask-image
I have an SVG that I am trying to use as mask-image that includes multiple strokes, however when being used as mask-image, the strokes aren't shown.


main {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 140px 60px 0 140px;
  &::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 100%;
    content: "", ;
    mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='46' height='1073' fill='none' viewBox='0 0 46 1073'%0A%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M43.75 0H1116.75V41H43.75z' transform='rotate(90 43.75 0)' %3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath stroke='green' stroke-width='2.5' d='M2 0v1072.9M44.75 0v1072.9' %3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath stroke='green' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2.5' d='M16.75 1071.65h27.28M29.84 1057.55h14.1M29.84 1043.45h14.1M29.84 1029.35h14.1M29.84 1015.24h14.1M16.66 1001.14h27.28M29.84 986.04h14.1M29.84 971.94h14.1M29.84 957.83h14.1M29.84 943.73h14.1M16.66 929.63h27.28M29.84 914.53h14.1M29.84 900.42h14.1M29.84 886.32h14.1M29.84 872.22h14.1M16.66 858.12h27.28M29.84 843.01h14.1M29.84 828.91h14.1M29.84 814.81h14.1M29.84 800.71h14.1M16.66 786.61h27.28M29.84 771.5h14.1M29.84 757.4h14.1M29.84 743.3h14.1M29.84 729.2h14.1M16.66 715.1h27.28M29.84 699.99h14.1M29.84 685.89h14.1M29.84 671.79h14.1M29.84 657.69h14.1M16.66 643.59h27.28M29.84 628.48h14.1M29.84 614.38h14.1M29.84 600.28h14.1M29.84 586.18h14.1M16.66 572.08h27.28M29.84 556.97h14.1M29.84 542.87h14.1M29.84 528.77h14.1M29.84 514.67h14.1M16.66 500.57h27.28M29.84 485.46h14.1M29.84 471.36h14.1M29.84 457.26h14.1M29.84 443.16h14.1M16.66 429.06h27.28M29.84 413.95h14.1M29.84 399.85h14.1M29.84 385.75h14.1M29.84 371.65h14.1M16.66 357.55h27.28M29.84 342.44h14.1M29.84 328.34h14.1M29.84 314.24h14.1M29.84 300.14h14.1M16.66 286.04h27.28M29.84 270.93h14.1M29.84 256.83h14.1M29.84 242.73h14.1M29.84 228.63h14.1M16.66 214.53h27.28M29.84 199.42h14.1M29.84 185.32h14.1M29.84 171.22h14.1M29.84 157.12h14.1M16.66 143.02h27.28M29.84 127.91h14.1M29.84 113.81h14.1M29.84 99.71h14.1M29.84 85.61h14.1M16.66 71.5h27.28M29.84 56.4h14.1M29.84 42.3h14.1M29.84 28.2h14.1M29.84 14.09h14.1' %3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  }
}
<main></main>




The HTML code is just simply  and the strokes are not showing up at all, but if I inspect main, then the svg is being imported

Currently your mask SVG is fully opaque.
Due to the default mask-mode match-source the element is not masked according to the luminance of the darker scale "ticks".
You can change the mask-mode to mask-mode: luminance but propably you should also delete the white background <path>


.masked {
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  mask-mode: luminance;
  mask-size: contain;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='46' height='1073' fill='none' viewBox='0 0 46 1073'%0A%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M43.75 0H1116.75V41H43.75z' transform='rotate(90 43.75 0)' %3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath stroke='green' stroke-width='2.5' d='M2 0v1072.9M44.75 0v1072.9' %3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath stroke='green' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2.5' d='M16.75 1071.65h27.28M29.84 1057.55h14.1M29.84 1043.45h14.1M29.84 1029.35h14.1M29.84 1015.24h14.1M16.66 1001.14h27.28M29.84 986.04h14.1M29.84 971.94h14.1M29.84 957.83h14.1M29.84 943.73h14.1M16.66 929.63h27.28M29.84 914.53h14.1M29.84 900.42h14.1M29.84 886.32h14.1M29.84 872.22h14.1M16.66 858.12h27.28M29.84 843.01h14.1M29.84 828.91h14.1M29.84 814.81h14.1M29.84 800.71h14.1M16.66 786.61h27.28M29.84 771.5h14.1M29.84 757.4h14.1M29.84 743.3h14.1M29.84 729.2h14.1M16.66 715.1h27.28M29.84 699.99h14.1M29.84 685.89h14.1M29.84 671.79h14.1M29.84 657.69h14.1M16.66 643.59h27.28M29.84 628.48h14.1M29.84 614.38h14.1M29.84 600.28h14.1M29.84 586.18h14.1M16.66 572.08h27.28M29.84 556.97h14.1M29.84 542.87h14.1M29.84 528.77h14.1M29.84 514.67h14.1M16.66 500.57h27.28M29.84 485.46h14.1M29.84 471.36h14.1M29.84 457.26h14.1M29.84 443.16h14.1M16.66 429.06h27.28M29.84 413.95h14.1M29.84 399.85h14.1M29.84 385.75h14.1M29.84 371.65h14.1M16.66 357.55h27.28M29.84 342.44h14.1M29.84 328.34h14.1M29.84 314.24h14.1M29.84 300.14h14.1M16.66 286.04h27.28M29.84 270.93h14.1M29.84 256.83h14.1M29.84 242.73h14.1M29.84 228.63h14.1M16.66 214.53h27.28M29.84 199.42h14.1M29.84 185.32h14.1M29.84 171.22h14.1M29.84 157.12h14.1M16.66 143.02h27.28M29.84 127.91h14.1M29.84 113.81h14.1M29.84 99.71h14.1M29.84 85.61h14.1M16.66 71.5h27.28M29.84 56.4h14.1M29.84 42.3h14.1M29.84 28.2h14.1M29.84 14.09h14.1' %3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.masked2 {
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  mask-mode: luminance;
  mask-size: contain;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='46' height='1073' fill='none' viewBox='0 0 46 1073'%0A%3E %3Cpath stroke='green' stroke-width='2.5' d='M2 0v1072.9M44.75 0v1072.9' %3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath stroke='green' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2.5' d='M16.75 1071.65h27.28M29.84 1057.55h14.1M29.84 1043.45h14.1M29.84 1029.35h14.1M29.84 1015.24h14.1M16.66 1001.14h27.28M29.84 986.04h14.1M29.84 971.94h14.1M29.84 957.83h14.1M29.84 943.73h14.1M16.66 929.63h27.28M29.84 914.53h14.1M29.84 900.42h14.1M29.84 886.32h14.1M29.84 872.22h14.1M16.66 858.12h27.28M29.84 843.01h14.1M29.84 828.91h14.1M29.84 814.81h14.1M29.84 800.71h14.1M16.66 786.61h27.28M29.84 771.5h14.1M29.84 757.4h14.1M29.84 743.3h14.1M29.84 729.2h14.1M16.66 715.1h27.28M29.84 699.99h14.1M29.84 685.89h14.1M29.84 671.79h14.1M29.84 657.69h14.1M16.66 643.59h27.28M29.84 628.48h14.1M29.84 614.38h14.1M29.84 600.28h14.1M29.84 586.18h14.1M16.66 572.08h27.28M29.84 556.97h14.1M29.84 542.87h14.1M29.84 528.77h14.1M29.84 514.67h14.1M16.66 500.57h27.28M29.84 485.46h14.1M29.84 471.36h14.1M29.84 457.26h14.1M29.84 443.16h14.1M16.66 429.06h27.28M29.84 413.95h14.1M29.84 399.85h14.1M29.84 385.75h14.1M29.84 371.65h14.1M16.66 357.55h27.28M29.84 342.44h14.1M29.84 328.34h14.1M29.84 314.24h14.1M29.84 300.14h14.1M16.66 286.04h27.28M29.84 270.93h14.1M29.84 256.83h14.1M29.84 242.73h14.1M29.84 228.63h14.1M16.66 214.53h27.28M29.84 199.42h14.1M29.84 185.32h14.1M29.84 171.22h14.1M29.84 157.12h14.1M16.66 143.02h27.28M29.84 127.91h14.1M29.84 113.81h14.1M29.84 99.71h14.1M29.84 85.61h14.1M16.66 71.5h27.28M29.84 56.4h14.1M29.84 42.3h14.1M29.84 28.2h14.1M29.84 14.09h14.1' %3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
<div class="masked"></div>
<div class="masked2"></div>



Basically, you can interpret transparency either by

luminance values: white/light=opaque; black/dark=transparent; gray=semi-transparent
alpha: existing opacity/transparency in image



body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.masked {
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 500px;
  mask-size: contain;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='46' height='1073' fill='none' viewBox='0 0 46 1073'><path fill='%23fff' d='M43.75 0H1116.75V41H43.75z' transform='rotate(90 43.75 0)'></path><path stroke='green' stroke-width='2.5' d='M2 0v1072.9M44.75 0v1072.9'></path><path stroke='green' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2.5' d='M16.75 1071.65h27.28M29.84 1057.55h14.1M29.84 1043.45h14.1M29.84 1029.35h14.1M29.84 1015.24h14.1M16.66 1001.14h27.28M29.84 986.04h14.1M29.84 971.94h14.1M29.84 957.83h14.1M29.84 943.73h14.1M16.66 929.63h27.28M29.84 914.53h14.1M29.84 900.42h14.1M29.84 886.32h14.1M29.84 872.22h14.1M16.66 858.12h27.28M29.84 843.01h14.1M29.84 828.91h14.1M29.84 814.81h14.1M29.84 800.71h14.1M16.66 786.61h27.28M29.84 771.5h14.1M29.84 757.4h14.1M29.84 743.3h14.1M29.84 729.2h14.1M16.66 715.1h27.28M29.84 699.99h14.1M29.84 685.89h14.1M29.84 671.79h14.1M29.84 657.69h14.1M16.66 643.59h27.28M29.84 628.48h14.1M29.84 614.38h14.1M29.84 600.28h14.1M29.84 586.18h14.1M16.66 572.08h27.28M29.84 556.97h14.1M29.84 542.87h14.1M29.84 528.77h14.1M29.84 514.67h14.1M16.66 500.57h27.28M29.84 485.46h14.1M29.84 471.36h14.1M29.84 457.26h14.1M29.84 443.16h14.1M16.66 429.06h27.28M29.84 413.95h14.1M29.84 399.85h14.1M29.84 385.75h14.1M29.84 371.65h14.1M16.66 357.55h27.28M29.84 342.44h14.1M29.84 328.34h14.1M29.84 314.24h14.1M29.84 300.14h14.1M16.66 286.04h27.28M29.84 270.93h14.1M29.84 256.83h14.1M29.84 242.73h14.1M29.84 228.63h14.1M16.66 214.53h27.28M29.84 199.42h14.1M29.84 185.32h14.1M29.84 171.22h14.1M29.84 157.12h14.1M16.66 143.02h27.28M29.84 127.91h14.1M29.84 113.81h14.1M29.84 99.71h14.1M29.84 85.61h14.1M16.66 71.5h27.28M29.84 56.4h14.1M29.84 42.3h14.1M29.84 28.2h14.1M29.84 14.09h14.1'></path></svg>");
}

.masked-match-source {
  mask-mode: match-source;
}

.masked-luminance {
  mask-mode: luminance;
}

.masked-luminance2 {
  mask-mode: luminance;
  mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='46' height='1073' fill='none' viewBox='0 0 46 1073'><path fill='black'  d='M43.75 0H1116.75V41H43.75z' transform='rotate(90 43.75 0)'></path><path stroke='green' stroke-width='2.5' d='M2 0v1072.9M44.75 0v1072.9'></path><path stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2.5' d='M16.75 1071.65h27.28M29.84 1057.55h14.1M29.84 1043.45h14.1M29.84 1029.35h14.1M29.84 1015.24h14.1M16.66 1001.14h27.28M29.84 986.04h14.1M29.84 971.94h14.1M29.84 957.83h14.1M29.84 943.73h14.1M16.66 929.63h27.28M29.84 914.53h14.1M29.84 900.42h14.1M29.84 886.32h14.1M29.84 872.22h14.1M16.66 858.12h27.28M29.84 843.01h14.1M29.84 828.91h14.1M29.84 814.81h14.1M29.84 800.71h14.1M16.66 786.61h27.28M29.84 771.5h14.1M29.84 757.4h14.1M29.84 743.3h14.1M29.84 729.2h14.1M16.66 715.1h27.28M29.84 699.99h14.1M29.84 685.89h14.1M29.84 671.79h14.1M29.84 657.69h14.1M16.66 643.59h27.28M29.84 628.48h14.1M29.84 614.38h14.1M29.84 600.28h14.1M29.84 586.18h14.1M16.66 572.08h27.28M29.84 556.97h14.1M29.84 542.87h14.1M29.84 528.77h14.1M29.84 514.67h14.1M16.66 500.57h27.28M29.84 485.46h14.1M29.84 471.36h14.1M29.84 457.26h14.1M29.84 443.16h14.1M16.66 429.06h27.28M29.84 413.95h14.1M29.84 399.85h14.1M29.84 385.75h14.1M29.84 371.65h14.1M16.66 357.55h27.28M29.84 342.44h14.1M29.84 328.34h14.1M29.84 314.24h14.1M29.84 300.14h14.1M16.66 286.04h27.28M29.84 270.93h14.1M29.84 256.83h14.1M29.84 242.73h14.1M29.84 228.63h14.1M16.66 214.53h27.28M29.84 199.42h14.1M29.84 185.32h14.1M29.84 171.22h14.1M29.84 157.12h14.1M16.66 143.02h27.28M29.84 127.91h14.1M29.84 113.81h14.1M29.84 99.71h14.1M29.84 85.61h14.1M16.66 71.5h27.28M29.84 56.4h14.1M29.84 42.3h14.1M29.84 28.2h14.1M29.84 14.09h14.1'></path></svg>");
}

.masked-alpha {
  mask-mode: alpha;
}

.masked-alpha2 {
  mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='46' height='1073' fill='none' viewBox='0 0 46 1073'><path fill='%23fff' fill-opacity='0' d='M43.75 0H1116.75V41H43.75z' transform='rotate(90 43.75 0)'></path><path stroke='green' stroke-width='2.5' d='M2 0v1072.9M44.75 0v1072.9'></path><path stroke='green' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2.5' d='M16.75 1071.65h27.28M29.84 1057.55h14.1M29.84 1043.45h14.1M29.84 1029.35h14.1M29.84 1015.24h14.1M16.66 1001.14h27.28M29.84 986.04h14.1M29.84 971.94h14.1M29.84 957.83h14.1M29.84 943.73h14.1M16.66 929.63h27.28M29.84 914.53h14.1M29.84 900.42h14.1M29.84 886.32h14.1M29.84 872.22h14.1M16.66 858.12h27.28M29.84 843.01h14.1M29.84 828.91h14.1M29.84 814.81h14.1M29.84 800.71h14.1M16.66 786.61h27.28M29.84 771.5h14.1M29.84 757.4h14.1M29.84 743.3h14.1M29.84 729.2h14.1M16.66 715.1h27.28M29.84 699.99h14.1M29.84 685.89h14.1M29.84 671.79h14.1M29.84 657.69h14.1M16.66 643.59h27.28M29.84 628.48h14.1M29.84 614.38h14.1M29.84 600.28h14.1M29.84 586.18h14.1M16.66 572.08h27.28M29.84 556.97h14.1M29.84 542.87h14.1M29.84 528.77h14.1M29.84 514.67h14.1M16.66 500.57h27.28M29.84 485.46h14.1M29.84 471.36h14.1M29.84 457.26h14.1M29.84 443.16h14.1M16.66 429.06h27.28M29.84 413.95h14.1M29.84 399.85h14.1M29.84 385.75h14.1M29.84 371.65h14.1M16.66 357.55h27.28M29.84 342.44h14.1M29.84 328.34h14.1M29.84 314.24h14.1M29.84 300.14h14.1M16.66 286.04h27.28M29.84 270.93h14.1M29.84 256.83h14.1M29.84 242.73h14.1M29.84 228.63h14.1M16.66 214.53h27.28M29.84 199.42h14.1M29.84 185.32h14.1M29.84 171.22h14.1M29.84 157.12h14.1M16.66 143.02h27.28M29.84 127.91h14.1M29.84 113.81h14.1M29.84 99.71h14.1M29.84 85.61h14.1M16.66 71.5h27.28M29.84 56.4h14.1M29.84 42.3h14.1M29.84 28.2h14.1M29.84 14.09h14.1'></path></svg>");
}
<p>mask-mode: match-source/alpha: No effect because we don't have any transparency</p>
<div class="masked masked-match-source"></div>
<div class="masked masked-alpha"></div>

<p>mask-mode: luminance: Black/dark color= transparent; White/light color= opaque; Gray/semi-dark=semi-transparent</p>
<p>Scale ticks are semitransparent due to green color ("semi-dark" color). Background rect is opaque due to white fill</p>
<div class="masked masked-luminance"></div>
<p>Scale ticks are semitransparent due to green color ("semi-dark" color). Background rect is transparent due to black fill</p>
<div class="masked masked-luminance2"></div>

<p>Scale ticks are opaque due to white color. Background rect is transparent due to black fill</p>
<div class="masked masked-alpha2"></div>




Thank you so much. However what if I wanted the lines to be green? Is it possible to achieve that?

Basically you mask image only provides transparency values. Colors are not inherited. The rendered color is defined by the background-color
